# Access Google Cloud SQL from SDK Shell

Tags: sql, postgresql, gcloud

I have created a PostgreSQL Instance in Google Cloud.
I can access the Instance and perform SQL actions using the Cloud Shell.

When i try to access the same from my local using the 'Google Cloud SDK Shell', it fails to connect to the instance,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud sql connect [my-instance] --user==user-name
Whitelisting your IP for incoming connection for 5 minutes...done.
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.connect) Could not whitelist client IP. Server did not reply with the whitelisted IP.
```

I have replaced my-instance and user-name with correct entries
Can someone guide me on how to access this database from my local SDK shell and not using the Cloud shell ?

Comment: Apparantly you need Cloud SQL Editor role. I don't know if this is relevant info in this case or not.

Comment: I'm going to investigate for you because this doesn't work for me either (although I have different errors). It appears that `gcloud sql connect` is some "sugar" that temporarily whitelists your machine's IP and then configures e.g. `psql` for you on-the-fly. Essentially this: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip#connect. Please try the instructions in that link for yourself. It should work. I'll get back to you with an update on why `gcloud sql connect` does not.

Comment: I encourage you to consider using the Cloud SQL Proxy too. The Proxy provides a consistent and secure mechanism for interacting with Cloud SQL instances and saves whitelisting IPs: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy

Comment: @DazWailkin , thanks for the links. I will go thru them and Update if that sought my issues.

Comment: Engineering confirmed that `gcloud sql connect` can be problematic and supported the recommendation to do this manually with the Cloud SQL Proxy. Sorry for the inconvenience! Work to resolve the issue with `gcloud sql connect` is  underway; it too will use the Cloud SQL Proxy.

Comment: I have been using gcloud sql connect which whitelisted my ip 5 minutes to connect and was working great, but in last 2 days, it just stopped working.  full script found here -> https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Databases/Could-not-allowlist-client-IP-but-last-3-months-just-fine/td-p/724445

Answer (score 3):

There are some [options to connect to your SQL instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-access-control#instanceaccess) depending on the client that you use, some of them are: Compute Engine, App Engine, mysql client, External applications.

I think your machine could be considered an external application, so you have to [follow this guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#appaccessIP) to authorize your Windows client machine. However, the recommended way is using [the cloudsqlproxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#proxy) since it will free you from whitelisting all connections.

Hope it help you!